# Prove that the Laplacian operator is positive definite

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let we have $\Omega = [0,1]\times[0,1] $ and boundary conditions: $u = 0$ when $y = 0$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$ on the other part of $\partial \Omega$. Prove that operator $A = -\Delta u$ is positive definite, which means $(-\Delta u, u) \ge m(u, u), \forall u$ for some $m > 0$.

Using Green's identity it is easy to prove that $\displaystyle (-\Delta u, u) = -\int\limits_{\Omega} (\Delta u u)dxdy = \int\limits_{\Omega} (\nabla u)^2 dxdy = (\nabla u, \nabla u) > 0$. But it does not mean positive definiteness yet. How can I prove exactly positive definiteness?

Great thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: @GyuEunLee, But Friedrichs inequality requires that $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$

Comment: Your domain is simple enough you can compute the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions explicitly.

Comment: @AlexGrey Ah, my mistake.